# C# Размер макета UWP. Задать фиксированный размер

Tags: c#, uwp

Рад приветствовать. Вопрос следующий: в Visual Studio создаю пустое приложение для Windows (во вкладке универсальные приложения Windows). Моя задача - сделать маленькую форму фиксированного (нерастягиваемого) размера (примерно 800х600 пикс). Я не знаю каким образом я могу этого добиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался выставлять для Page Width и Height, в конструкторе размер меняется, при сборке решения  размер макета все равно остается лошадиным на весь экран. Выставления для Page минимального и максимального ширины и высоты результата так же не дает.

Различные вариации выбора в этом окне так же ни к чему не приводят:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы я не менял при сборке решения и его запуске размер остается таким же:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста создать форму небольшого неизменяемого размера.

Comment: Думаю, что это невозможно. Вам придется делать адаптивный дизайн.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;`

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size { Height = 550, Width = 360 };
    ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
}
```